# Incorrect Syntax Error - c#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I am getting an error

> Incorrect syntax near '('

I am updating a product from the database when a specific product code is entered.

How can this be done?

```
// Update product with supplier code entered
DialogResult dr = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to update this product?", "Update Product Details", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);

if (dr == DialogResult.Yes)
{
    try
    {
         using (SqlConnection SQLcon = new SqlConnection("Data Source = .\\SqlExpress;" + "Initial Catalog=NCAShop;" + "Integrated Security=True;"))
         {
             SQLcon.Open();

             using (SqlCommand addProduct = new SqlCommand("UPDATE dbo.[NCAProduct] (ProductName, SupplierCode, Cost, RetailPrice, Quantity, BestBefore) VALUES ('" + txtUPProductName.Text + "', " + txtUPSupplierCode.Text + ", " + txtUPCost.Text + ", " + txtUPRetail.Text + ", " + txtUPQuantity.Text + ", @date) WHERE ProductCode = " + txtUPProdCode.Text, SQLcon))
             {
                 addProduct.Parameters.Add("@date", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = bestBeforeDTP.Value.Date;
                 addProduct.ExecuteNonQuery();
             }
         }

         MessageBox.Show("This product has been successfully added to the database!");
    }
    catch (Exception error2)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(error2.ToString());
    }
}
else if (dr == DialogResult.No)
{
    // Program will continue if user selects 'No'
}
```

Comment: Your `UPDATE`syntax is false. Would you like to insert data or update data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use to correct syntax for an SQL update. The syntax is:

```
UPDATE table SET column = value, ... WHERE ...
```

You're mixing it with the `INSERT` syntax, which is

```
INSERT INTO Table (Column, ...) VALUES (Value, ...)
```

I suppose that you actually want to do an `INSERT` anyway. In that case, replace the word `UPDATE` in your query with `INSERT INTO` and you should be fine.

PS: Oh and please - use parameters for all the values, not just the date.

Comment: +1000000 for mentioning the fact that this query is wide open to SQL injection.

Comment: Thanks - I think it's notable that the OP *knows* about parameterized queries, but then only uses them on one parameter...

Answer (score 0):

Use proper query formatting sometimes '[ ]'  these brackets create an error while executing the query in the DB and please use a proper conversion for specific database types. To prevent [sqlinjection attacks](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection) I used a [SqlCommandParameter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yy6y35y8(v=vs.110).aspx) for each user provided input. You can use the query given below:

```
string query = @"UPDATE dbo.[NCAProduct] (
                       [ProductName], 
                       [SupplierCode], 
                       [Cost], 
                       [RetailPrice], 
                       [Quantity], 
                       [BestBefore]) VALUES 
                       (@txtUPProductName,
                        @txtUPSupplierCode,
                        @txtUPCost,
                        @txtUPRetail,
                        @txtUPQuantity, 
                        @date) 
                        WHERE [ProductCode] = @txtUPProdCode";
        using (SqlCommand addProduct = new SqlCommand(query, SQLcon))
        {
            addProduct.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = bestBeforeDTP.Value.Date;
            addProduct.Parameters.AddWithValue("@txtUPProductName", txtUPProductName.Text);
            addProduct.Parameters.AddWithValue("@txtUPSupplierCode", Convert.ToInt32(txtUPSupplierCode.Text));
            addProduct.Parameters.AddWithValue("@txtUPCost", Convert.ToInt32(txtUPCost.Text));
            addProduct.Parameters.AddWithValue("@txtUPRetail", Convert.ToInt32(txtUPRetail.Text));
            addProduct.Parameters.AddWithValue("@txtUPQuantity", Convert.ToInt32(txtUPQuantity.Text));
            addProduct.Parameters.AddWithValue("@txtUPProdCode", Convert.ToInt32(txtUPProdCode.Text));
            addProduct.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
```

Convert text to int64 or double if you are using bigint data type in database.

Comment: I think it's notable that the OP knows about parametrized queries, but then only uses them on one parameter.